# I've completed my contracts. Now what?

Tags: team-fortress-2

I completed the two contracts I was given (Scout and Heavy), and earned two of the 'Teufort' weapons for turning them in.

I expected to get some new contracts so I could continue to earn some more of the schmancy new weapons, but I can't seem to find out how to get more.

Do I need to buy the ticket again to unlock more contracts? If not, how are contracts assigned?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Derp, I should've read [the instructions](http://www.teamfortress.com/gunmettle/) more carefully:

> **Get your contracts here**
>   You'll be assigned **two skill-based contracts each week for the length of the Gun Mettle Campaign**. Every contract will give you a new challenge, as well as an advanced-level objective worth bonus points. Get a kill with a reflected projectile as Pyro. Survive 1000 damage in a single life as Heavy. Kill an airborne enemy with your secondary weapon as Soldier. Whenever you complete a contract, you'll earn a campaign-exclusive weapon or unlockable weapon case.

Live and let learn I guess.

Comment: Valve handed out a third contract when they went "Oh @#$%, we forgot to add Teufort and Craftsmann cases to the Contract drop list, so we're not selling any Gunmettle keys.  Quick, give everyone another contract so we can make some money!"

Comment: @Powerlord - Heh, I wondered about that one :P

Answer (score 1):

Contracts appear to be given out twice weekly on Saturdays and Tuesdays. Wait until then to figure out what off-class you get to struggle through.